# Procedural Database Code vs Multiple Database Calls

Tags: sql, node.js, database, plpgsql

So this is a pretty high-level question…

I’m designing a database and am unsure where to put the procedural logic governing complex queries. I see two possible options, which are as follows:

1) Define the logic in **procedural database code**.

So for example, in the database (ex: PLpgSQL):

```
create function A …
create function B …
create function C …
create function main {
    a = select * from A() …
    b = select * from B() … where a …
    c = select * from C() … where b …
    return c;
}
```

and then in the surrounding server environment (ex: Node.js):

```
result = query(‘main’);
```

2) Define the logic in the surrounding server environment and simply make **multiple database calls** to the simpler database functions.

So for example, in the database:

```
create function A …
create function B …
create function C …
```

and then in the surrounding server environment:

```
a = query(‘A’);
b = query(‘B … where a …’);
c = query(‘C … where b …’);
```

Essentially I’m asking about the merits of putting code in procedural database languages vs writing queries in the surrounding server environment, and/or the speed trade-offs associated with running procedural database code vs making multiple database calls from the surrounding server environment.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Excellent though controversial question.  I have a lot of experience here so here is what I can say:

1. Saving round trips only makes sense as a justification when you can save a lot of them, and
2. The real benefits are elsewhere.

The big benefit of stored procedures is that they enable you to think about encapsulating functionality behind interfaces and then optimizing that functionality.  In other words, saving 2 round trips is not a big deal but being able to optimize the queries involved will often save much more.  If the interfaces are sane and the encapsulation good this has significant benefits.

The major drawback has to do with the fact that people can misuse stored procedures, put non-transactional things in them (like sending emails) and the like, combined with the fact that usually you have an inability to expand argument lists effectively without breaking encapsulation contracts (I don't think variadic functions are a major fix to this).  Oracle of course has revision based editions to help with the latter problem but PostgreSQL does not.  Instead on postgresql I tend to write service locators to stored procedures to fix that problem.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your answer :) To give more detail, I'm writing a web interface that's basically a gui wrapper for a textual search of the database. So you're saying that either parsing the contents of the web form (which can be arbitrarily complex) in Node vs putting the same logic in PLpgSQL (by playing with many many procedure parameters, or passing a JSON object, etc), they're essentially the same speed-wise and I should do whichever is easier, then wait to optimize later when I can see where the actual slowdown is? That makes sense; just making sure I understand you :)

Comment: This starts from a different question:  How do you intend to use your database?  Then the next is:  How do you want to interface with your database?  It is easier, I think, to focus on specific questions than abstract solutions.

Comment: As a general rule I'd suggest encapsulation in PL/SQL is the way to go.  One problem with trying to do all data manipulation in the app, and then optimizing later is that scalability is hard to test until it's too late.  Also think about deployment futures: are you heading to cloud deployment where latencies may not be as quick - the roundtrips may look less attractive.